# How to kill Google Drive File Stream process in OSX

Tags: macos

How to kill **[Google Drive File Stream](https://www.google.com/drive/download/)** process in OSX?

Using `sudo kill -9 <PID>`, the process appears to keep itself alive. Every time I try to kill it, the PID changes in Activity Monitor.

Comment: i used `sudo killall -9 "Google Drive"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The helper application may be keeping it alive, not sure ... but it's possible to completely shut this application down by killing both the helper application and the stream application by name:

```
sudo killall -9 "Google Drive File Stream Helper"
sudo killall -9 "Google Drive File Stream"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the longhand way to kill all the Google Drive processes in one hit.

List process IDs (optional, useful to query beforehand or verify afterwards):

```
ps aux | grep "Google Drive" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Kill:

```
ps aux | grep "Google Drive" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```